# I can enter U+0008 (backspace character) into a chat message

Tags: bug, chat, unicode

I typed [a chat message including two pings](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4770809#4770809). I believe I tab-completed @rumtscho and fully typed @MarthaF (since she doesn't tab complete). However, other people tell me that a Unicode character was inserted into the message; I can't see it:

[image]

Originally, I abandoned this bug report for a lack of reproducibility. But on another machine, I can see the character and managed to reproduce it: press tab, then press backspace. It works anywhere in a message, not just in a @-ping. (Actually, it seems that you just need to un-focus the input box; clicking elsewhere then hitting backspace works, too)

- First machine is Firefox 12 (Iceweasel) on Debian GNU/Linux AMD64, testing+unstable. No user scripts. Greasemonkey is installed, but disabled in the extension manager
- Second machine is Firefox 10 (Iceweasel) on Debian GNU/Linux AMD64, testing+unstable. No user scripts, Greasemonkey not even installed
- Third machine (just tested) is Firefox 11 (Iceweasel) on Debian GNU/Linux AMD64. Greasemonkey installed and enabled, and there is a global userscript.
- Does *not* happen on Chromium 18.0.1025.151, running on machine #3.

So far, that's all the machines I've tested on, and it happens on all of them. It only happens in chat.

Easiest way to produce it is to click on the page background, somewhere outside the text box, to un-focus the text box. Then press backspace. Note that not all browsers will *display* the character, even if its there (check [this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4808501#4808501) to see if yours does)

Comment: Sounds to me that your Backspace is messing up, and pressing Tab has little to do with it. Does it actually remove the character you're trying to remove? For your browsers, does it also happen outside Chat, or in fields where there's no auto complete at all? Maybe even [regular posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)? (And it's odd you actually need to remove a tab character: in my browsers, I cannot "type" a tab as pressing Tab gets me to the next input field when there's no auto-completion match, but that might be different in Chat.)

Comment: (As an aside, some [online character-to-UTF8 encoder](http://coderstoolbox.net/string/) might help debugging.)

Comment: Since `U+0008` is the backspace character (`U+0009` is tab), @Arjan is probably right. Do you use any user scripts? JavaScript writing `String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)` to the input field or textarea would insert a backspace character instead of deleting the previous one.

Comment: No, there aren't any user scripts; Greasemonkey isn't even installed. Tab was just to de-activate the textbox, apparently (tab itself isn't inserted). The first backspace just inserts ^H, it doesn't delete a character. Second backspace works as expected. It only happens on chat.SE.

Comment: Apparently still present: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296385

Comment: Happens on IE, too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Steps reproduce this behavior with Firefox:

1. Open the chat in a new tab.

   (There can't be any history in the tab, since pressing <kbd>backspace</kbd> would abandon the page.)
2. Remove the focus from the `<textarea>`.

   (Pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> when there's nothing to autocomplete does this.)
3. Press <kbd>backspace</kbd>.

I also think that I've isolated the faulty code in [master-chat.js](http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/Js/master-chat.js?v=b89a07ba0c6d):

```
$(document).bind("keypress",function(a){if(!a.ctrlKey&&!a.altKey&&!a.metaKey){var b;if(a.which&&13!=a.which&&32!=a.which&&"input"!=(b=a.target.nodeName.toLowerCase())&&"textarea"!=b&&0==$(a.target).closest(".popup").length&&(b=String.fromCharCode(a.keyCode||a.which)))d.focus(),$.browser.mozilla&&d.val(d.val()+b)}}
```

The idea is to directly write to the `<textarea>` when a key is pressed, even if it doesn't have focus.

That works well in most cases, but not when pressing <kbd>backspace</kbd>:

1. `b=String.fromCharCode(a.keyCode||a.which)` sets `b="\x08"`.
2. `d.val(d.val()+b)` writes `U+0008` to the textarea.

Note:

- This isn't a problem in Chrome, since pressing <kbd>backspace</kbd> doesn't trigger `keypress` in situations where Chrome attempts to go back in history.
- Pressing <kbd>backspace</kbd> a second time behaves like expected, since the `<textarea>` has focus now.

Comment: "This isn't a problem in Chrome, since it attempts to go back in history when pressing backspace." Doesn't Firefox do that too?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: I didn't express myself correctly. Firefox also uses backspace for going back in history, but it triggers `keypress` in addition.

Comment: Nice, Sherlock. As an aside, but related: when I was using Firefox in OS X, I also [used keyconfig to disable Delete for navigation](http://superuser.com/questions/24166/can-i-seize-control-of-cmd-left-in-osx/24199#24199) (here, Delete being the Mac's name for Backspace), as sometimes using editors such as TinyMCE would make Delete go back while editing... Troublesome key :-)

Comment: Backspace to go back in history? Must be some weird Windows thing. Firefox on Linux doesn't do that (instead, it's alt-left)

Comment: @derobert: Indeed. On Windows, backspace and alt-left work both. The strange thing is that backspace doesn't work in Chrome on Ubuntu (I never picked up on this, since I don't use backspace that way), but it still doesn't trigger `keypress`...

Comment: I can reproduce this bug in Firefox 32.0.3 under Windows 8.1: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17966600#17966600 (not visible, but seems to be stored internally)

Answer (score 5):

As Dennis has correctly noted, the culprit is the SE event handler that tries to capture keypresses anywhere on the page and redirect them to the input area.  The problem is that the event handler is *not* smart enough to realize that (even after accounting for modifier keys, enter and space, which it already does) not all keypress events actually correspond to new characters that could or should just be appended to the input.

A better way to implement the event handler might be to have it re-trigger the keypress event on the input area instead, and rely on the browser's default event handling behavior to actually update the text.  However, as a crude interim fix, I came up with the following code, which will install its own event handler to intercept any keypress events corresponding to control characters (character code < 32) and prevent them from reaching the SE event handler:

```
$('body#chat-body').on( 'keypress', function (e) {
    if ( e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey ) return;
    if ( !e.which || e.which >= 32 ) return;
    e.stopPropagation();
} );
```

I have included this fix in version 1.4 of the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch), a collection of client-side CSS and JavaScript fixes packaged as a GreaseMonkey-style user script.  If you're using a compatible browser (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, possibly Safari and others, but unfortunately not IE or most mobile browsers), please give it a try!