# Glitch in chat that allows me to produce a backspace character literal

Tags: bug, chat

I was editing a post over in the Math Stack Exchange chat. I clicked in chat once (like to click off the box) and hit backspace to go back a page. Weirdly enough, a weird symbol appeared. I could replicate this arbitrarily to produce blank messages. I searched the ascii character code and apparently it is ascii code 8 which corresponds to the "backspace character". Apparently, the box in chat interprets that as a symbol being typed instead of as an actual command to erase.

UPDATE

---

Cause I happen to know a bit of html, I decided to use an html interpreter thingy to try and narrow down the lines of code that are producing the bug. I might make a duplicate over on stack overflow later to see if they can help get everything broken down.

The code I am currently breaking down piece by piece (i.e. controlled erasure of lines of code) is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/Js/master-chat.js?v=41e5f777e32e"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function IMAGE(f) { return ("//cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/img/" + f); }
  </script>
   </head>
   <body id="chat-body">
  <div id="container">
     <div id="main">
        <div id="input-area">
           <table id="input-table" width="100%"><tbody>
              <tr>
              <div id="bubble">
                    <textarea id="input"></textarea>
                 </div>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
  </div>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function()
  {
     var chat = StartChat({
        sound: {
           file: "//cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/se.mp3",
           vol: 55,
           swfPath: "//cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat"
        },
        may_bookmark: true,
        ws: true,
        desktopNotify: false
        },
                176971,
                {
                    id: 59182,
                    host: 'math.stackexchange.com',
                    deleted: false,
                    frozen: false
                },
                null,
                false,
                false,
                {});
CHAT.RoomUsers.initPresent([
    {id: 176971, name: ("TheGreatDuck"), email_hash: ("!https://i.stack.imgur.com/fude2.png?s=128&g=1"), reputation: 2295, last_post: 1495568919,is_owner:true }

]);
        });
  </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

[The editor I'm using.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit)

Comment: No repro on Chrome 58 (Windows). What browser? Also try in an incognito tab (with no extensions loaded) to rule out an extension.

Comment: @JasonC internet explorer. I don't use extensions, period.

Comment: The answers in the linked dupe have the culprit code, as well as a patch.

Comment: @JasonC except this probably isn't the same issue as it is occurring in a different browser.

Comment: The description indicates that it is precisely the same issue, and that other report isn't browser specific.

Comment: @JasonC alrighty then